# Como comparar la hora en java Script

Tags: javascript

Hola como puedo comparar la hora en java script si tengo un array de objetos en el que me dan una lista de películas y tengo que devolver un array con las películas que su duración sea menor a una hora (1 hs). Este es el array con los objetos adentro:

```
var array = [
  { nombre: 'Spider-Man: Sin camino a casa', estreno: 2022, duracion: '1:45' },
  { nombre: 'Rambo', estreno: 2000, duracion: '2:30 hs' },
  { nombre: 'Batman', estreno: 2022, duracion: '58 min' },
];
```

Hasta ahora voy asi pero no se como comparar la hora porque obvio que 55min me tira que es mayor a 1hs:

```
function devolverArray() {
  var nuevoArr = [];
  for (let = i; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].duracion > '1 hs') {
      nuevoArr.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return nuevoArr;
}
```

Ayuda plis!!

Comment: Spiderman dura un minuto con 45 segundos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te adjunto mi solución, la explicación te lo dejo en los comentarios de cada línea de código:

```js
var peliculas = [
  { nombre: 'Spider-Man: Sin camino a casa', estreno: 2022, duracion: '1:45' },
  { nombre: 'Rambo', estreno: 2000, duracion: '2:30 hs' },
  { nombre: 'Batman', estreno: 2022, duracion: '58 min' },
];

function devolverArray(peliculas) {
  // Inicializo un array para almacenar el resultado final.
  var menorUnaHora = [];
  // Recorro el array "peliculas".
  for (let i = 0; i < peliculas.length; i++) {
    // Obtengo los valores de la clave "duracion", ya que solo eso nos importa.
    let duracion = peliculas[i].duracion;
    // Obtengo el numero de minutos y horas con match() => ["1", "45"], ["2", "30"], ["58"].
    let match = duracion.match(/\d+/g);
    // De lo encontrado con el match, obtengo solo el 1er elemento.
    let minutos = Number(match[0]);
    // Verifico si hay la palabra "min" en los valores de "duracion".
    if (duracion.includes("min")) {
      // Si es que hay, no multiplico los minutos (ya que son minutos!!).
      minutos = minutos;
    } else {
      // Si no hay, es porque son horas, entonces los multiplico por 60 para tener la duración de minutos.
      minutos = minutos * 60;
    }
    // Entonces obtenemos la duración en horas dividiendo los minutos entre 60 para saber cual es menor de 1 hora.
    let duracionTotal = minutos / 60;
    // Si el resultado es menor a 1, quiere decir que es menor a 1 hora...
    if (duracionTotal < 1) {
      // Y entonces pusheo ese elemento al array...
      menorUnaHora.push(peliculas[i]);
    }
  }
  // Y retorno el array final.
  return menorUnaHora;
}

console.log(devolverArray(peliculas));
```

Comment: Gracias!! Me quedo muy claro :)

Comment: un gusto ayudarle, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que debes hacer para comparar la duracion de las peliculas es pasarlo todo a minutos, podrias hacerlo asi:

```js
function durationToMinutes(duration) {
    // si la duracion es menor a 60, es porque es solo minutos y se retorna solo convirtiendo a numero
    if (duration < 60) return +duration

    // si la duracion es mayor a 60, se separa en horas y minutos
    let [hours, minutes] = duration.split(':');

    // se convierten a numeros y se retorna la suma de horas y minutos
    return +hours * 60 + +minutes;
}
```

esta funcion recibira el string y lo convertira en minutos

ahora en vez de crear un nuevo array podemos usar el metodo filter para quedarnos solo con las peliculas que cumplan la condicion que deseamos.
algo como esto:

```js
return movies.filter(movie =>
    durationToMinutes(movie.duracion) <= duration
)
```

y ya todo esto lo podemos unificar en una funcion que devuelva nuestras peliculas:

```js
function durationToMinutes(duration) {
    // quitamos las letras que indican horas y minutos
    duration = duration.replace('hs', '').replace('min', '')

    // si la duracion es menor a 60, es porque es solo minutos y se retorna solo convirtiendo a numero
    if (duration < 60) return +duration

    // si la duracion es mayor a 60, se separa en horas y minutos
    let [hours, minutes] = duration.split(':')

    // se convierten a numeros y se retorna la suma de horas y minutos
    return +hours * 60 + +minutes
}

function getMoviesByDuration(movies, duration) {
    // convertimos la duracion a minutos
    duration = durationToMinutes(duration)

    // filtramos las peliculas que tengan la duracion indicada
    return movies.filter(movie =>
        durationToMinutes(movie.duracion) <= duration
    )
}


const movies = [
    { nombre: 'Spider-Man: Sin camino a casa', estreno: 2022, duracion: '1:45' },
    { nombre: 'Rambo', estreno: 2000, duracion: '2:30 hs' },
    { nombre: 'Batman', estreno: 2022, duracion: '58 min' },
]

console.log(getMoviesByDuration(movies, '1:00 hs'))
```